# Regex is match just if a character is not present

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am looking for a regex that finds the match only and only if either the word KO or the word OK is not present within the string (regardless of what is before and after).

I tried this:

[^OK|KO]

But it doesn't work.

example of what I would like to match:

- ```
                    20032023
  ```

example of what I would like NOT to match:

- 20032023  KO
- OK     123456   20032023

Comment: Try: `(?!.*\b(OK|KO)\b).+`

Comment: `[^OK|KO]` matches exactly one character, any character except for `O`, `K` or `|` (which are the characters listed in the character class after the starting `^`; the duplicates are ignored.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this `(?!.*(OK|KO).*)^.+$`. here `^.+$` is a main match (it matches whole lines), and `(!?....)` piece makes the negation, so matches that also contain OK|KO won't be taken